# Laravel 5 Model Inheritance - returning parent data when getting child mode

Tags: laravel, inheritance, eloquent

So I have this crazy idea that has to do with Laravel and model inheritance. I would like to configure a set of models with a single parent but when I request the child model I would like the data returned. For example I would have a Contacts model which is the parent:

```
Contacts: id, first_name, last_name, image
```

Then I would have a series of contact types that inherit from Contacts. Each of these child models would have their own set of fields (i.e. for members I need to know when they joined,etc. but for volunteers I might need to know if they have an up-to-date first-aid certificate). Here are a few examples:

```
Members: contact_id, joined_on, birthday, medical_concerns
Volunteers: contact_id, current_first_aid, interests
Staff: contact_id, pay_rate
```

I would love to be able to do something like:

```
$members = \App\Member::all();
```

and have the contact AND member data returned as if everything was one row, like this:

```
+---+------------+-----------+-------+------------+------------+------------------+
|id | first_name | last_name | image | joined_on  | birthday   | medical_concerns |
+---+------------+-----------+-------+------------+------------+------------------+
| 1 | Fred       | Bloggs    | null  | 2015-01-01 | 1993-10-22 | false            |
| 2 | Jim        | Phillips  | null  | 2016-04-30 | 1987-09-22 | true             |
+---+------------+-----------+-------+------------+------------+------------------+
```

And to make it a little more difficult I would like all of the relationships that apply to the parent to work for the child. So I could do something like this:

```
$members = \App\Member::find(1)->phone
```

And, even though the Member model doesn't have a relationship defined to the Phone model it would return the phone related to the Contact because the parent has that relationship.

I would also like to be able to specify columns that don't belong to the child when retrieving data and not have Laravel throw an error:

```
$members = \App\Member::all(['first_name','last_name','joined_on'])
```

I have messed around with overriding the Eloquent model and writing my own version of the all and find methods which is working but it looks like I may have to override all of the methods to get this to work and maybe that would be more work than just forgoing Eloquent and looking for other (or my own bespoke) solution.

So I guess my questions is: Is there an "easy" way to do this with Laravel or am I trying to make it do things that it was never intended to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this:

```
$members = \App\Members::with('contact')->all();
```

Of course your Members model should have defined the belongsTo relation to the contact model.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an "easy" way to do this with Laravel or am I trying to make it do things that it was never intended to do?

Yes.

Eloquent doen't manage inheritance in this way. It might be better to implement [polymorphic relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) instead.

However, overriding just this bit seems to serve your purposes:

```
abstract class ContactSubclass extends Contact
{
    protected $with = 'parent';

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Contact::class, 'contact_id');
    }

    public function newQuery()
    {
        $contactTable = (new Contact())->getTable();
        $thisTable = (new static())->getTable();

        $builder = parent::newQuery();
        $builder->join($contactTable, "$thisTable.contact_id", '=', "$contactTable.id");

        return $builder;
    }

    public function newFromBuilder($attributes = [], $connection = null)
    {
        $model = parent::newFromBuilder($attributes, $connection);

        if ($model->parent) {
            $model->setRawAttributes(array_merge($model->parent->getAttributes(), $model->getAttributes()), true);
        }

        return $model;
    }

    protected function getRelationshipFromMethod($method)
    {
        if (method_exists(parent::class, $method)) {
            return $this->parent->getRelationshipFromMethod($method);
        }

        return parent::getRelationshipFromMethod($method);
    }
}
```

Have `Member` and other subclasses extend this class (or add these overrides in each class that extends `Contact`).

(I haven't tested it thoroughly, give it a try. Also, this won't handle eager loads directly; try to find what to override if you want to support that.)